# kendo ui mobile forms without kendo.ui.Application

Tags: kendo-ui

since kendo ui 2014 release, we are able to mix kendoui Web and Mobile components.
The thing is that I want to use the Kendo UI Mobile Forms in a Web (Desktop) application.

I've tried the KendoDropDownList from KendoUI Web but it react oddly when using touch based hardware... the dropdown always close when scolling on my wp8 device.

So I tought that the KendoUI Mobile Dropdownlist would be a nice thing to implement, but it requires kendo.mobile.Application to work.

This is not an option in my case since my I use Angular Js as SPA.

So my question is,  is there anyway I can use KendoUI Mobile form without using kendo.mobile.Application with the current Q1 2014 release ?